# why typescript ask for generic type while already provided arguments

Tags: typescript

For example, I thought `P` should be inferred from the argument `p`. But when I'm using it, ts still requires me to fill `P`?

```js
const numberStringConverter = <T extends string | number,P extends {x: any}>(p: P): T => {
  if(typeof p.x === 'string'){
    return Number(p.x) as T
  }
  if(typeof p.x === 'number'){
    return String(p.x) as T
  }
  return p.x as T;
}
const ret = numberStringConverter<string>({x:1}) // Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.
```

I felt similar with https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571, but not sure.

This is a simplified case. I know we can write this case in another way.

Comment: It is all or nothing

Comment: P doesn’t need to be a generic

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, in this case. I simplified the original case.

Comment: @DanielA.White You mean we have to provide all generic params or 0 generic params?

Comment: ms/TS#10571 is indeed the issue, and without [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) or something like it you need workarounds as described in the linked q/a above.

Answer (score 0):

`P extends {x: any}` here  you say to send any extended object of type `{x:any}`

Here you will need to report this as `One` and `Two` class will also be correct

```
interface Base {x:any}

interface One extends Base {
  y?:string
}

interface Two extends Base {
  z?:string
}


const numberStringConverter = <T extends string | number,P extends Base >(p: P): T => {
  if(typeof p.x === 'string'){
    return Number(p.x) as T
  }
  if(typeof p.x === 'number'){
    return String(p.x) as T
  }
  return p.x as T;
}


 numberStringConverter<string,One>({x:1});
 numberStringConverter<string,Two>({x:1});
```

If only one class is accepted, you should not use extends. You should pass the class directly as a parameter

```
const numberStringConverter2 = <T extends string | number,>(p: Base): T => {
      if(typeof p.x === 'string'){
        return Number(p.x) as T
      }
      if(typeof p.x === 'number'){
        return String(p.x) as T
      }
      return p.x as T;
    }
```

You can also use it this way. If `Generic` did not specify a type, it would be `any`.

```
    const numberStringConverter = <T extends string | number,P extends {x: any}=any>(p: P): T => {
      if(typeof p.x === 'string'){
        return Number(p.x) as T
      }
      if(typeof p.x === 'number'){
        return String(p.x) as T
      }
      return p.x as T;
    }
    
    
     numberStringConverter<string>({x:1});
     numberStringConverter<string>({x:1});
    
    
    // The problem with this usage is that the ts compiler will not give an error here 
//and the p.x line in the function will throw an error
    // you'll have to realize it at runtime
     numberStringConverter<string>(5);
```

But I think that would be the best use in your case.

```
interface Base { x:any}

const numberStringConverter = <T extends string | number,P extends Base =Base>(p: P): T => {
  if(typeof p.x === 'string'){
    return Number(p.x) as T
  }
  if(typeof p.x === 'number'){
    return String(p.x) as T
  }
  return p.x as T;
}


 numberStringConverter<string>({x:1});
 numberStringConverter<string>({x:1});

 // ts compiler will show error
 numberStringConverter<string>(5);
```

`P extends Base =Base` where you specify that this type is used by default unless a special generic type is given.